# function which has as its input a vector where each element is a positive integer and returns each element of the input vector which is a cube number

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function which has as its input a vector where each element is a positive integer and returns each element of the input vector which is a cube number.

This is my code so far:

```
positivecube<- function(x){
 b<-round(x^(1/3), digits=6)
 b%%1==0 &&
 b!=1
return(x[b])
    }
```

I'm struggling to remove the 1s from the final vector and to also convert them back to the original cube number. Any help would be great, thank you

Comment: `x[b %% 1==0 & b!=1]` should be what is returned. At the moment you're not using any of your checks to subset the original `x`

Answer (score 0):

You could return the subset of x where the absolute difference between the cube root and the cube root rounded to the nearest integer is very small:

```r
positivecube <- function(x) x[abs(round(x^(1/3)) - x^(1/3)) < 1e-8]

positivecube(1:100)
#> [1]  1  8 27 64
```